# How to convert a column that have integer values and string values i.e different currency 50 USD, 70 YEN, 34 CAD

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0

Hello guys I have a table that checks the difference between dates and display as a label the difference bewteen the dates. After that I want to convert a column that have currency with integers and strings along them e.g 50 USD, 70 YEN, 34 CAD. I am interested to pull the column with currency value and multiply with the no. of days displayed by the label that captures the date difference then bind to another label that display the final results. Please any help on how to go about. Here is my sample code that fetches the date difference and after calucating it displays. When I try multiplying nothing displays on both labels

```
 try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

           
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "getBookIssuing";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MemberId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtMembeReturnId.Text.Trim();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@BookId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtReturnBookId.Text.Trim();
            cmd.Connection = con;              
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count >= 1) ;
            {

                //Calculate No. of Late Days
                DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/M/dd"));
                DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["DueDate"].ToString());
                string str= dt.Rows[0]["PenaltyRate"].ToString();
                float x = Convert.ToSingle(str);
                if (d1 > d2)
                {
                    TimeSpan t = d1 - d2;
                    double latedaysno = t.TotalDays;
                    Labellatedays.Text = latedaysno.ToString();
                    double penalty = latedaysno * x;
                    Labelpenalty.Text = penalty.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    Labellatedays.Text = "0";
                    Labelpenalty.Text = "0";
                }
            }
```

Comment: A column *cannot* have both `int` and `varchar` values; a column can only have 1 data type.

Comment: We cannot read your mind, see your screen, examine your database, or run your queries and code. Where is this column and what exactly does it contain? If it is a part of the resultset of your stored procedure, then why not have the procedure split the two values as separate columns (or more likely - not combine them into a single one)?

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue rises when you retrieve the penaltyRate column
if you are sure that all the values came as [number][currency]
your code should probably look like this

```
 string str= dt.Rows[0]["PenaltyRate"].ToString().Split(' ')[0];
            float x = Convert.ToSingle(str);
```